# Using TryCast to return DBNull instead of Nothing

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a a simple function in VB.net which will take a few parameters for use with TryCast.

My goal is to have a function I can use in place of TryCast which instead of returning Nothing when it fails it should return DbNull.

I just can't seem to get anything to work despite much searching.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have to have some specific return type for your function. So you can write a function with a signature like this:

```
Public Function TryCast(Of T)(ByVal item As Object) As T
```

But you will *never* be able to make it do what you want, because the type of `T` is *never* going to be DBNull (okay, maybe it *could* happen, but hopefully you get the idea).

Put another way, the type system blocks this. On the one hand, you want to be perfectly explicit about the return type (hence, the cast). On the other hand, you want to be able to return a completely different type. .Net does not allow this, even with dynamic typing. Either a method returns a *single* fixed type, or it is not declared to return a type at all.

With `Option Explicit` turned off, you might be able to go for something like this:

```
Public Function TryCast(Of T)(ByVal item As Object)
```

However, I don't think this will do what you want, either, because now the returned value is effectively the same as object, and you lose the benefit of any casting.

It works with the normal TryCast() for `Nothing`, because Nothing can be assigned to any type. DBNull is itself a fixed type, and so is not as flexible.

Comment: Thanks for the input. That would explain why I could not get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - not possible, and here is why. Suppose you have the following code:

```
Class A
End Class
Class B : Inherits A
End Class
Class C
End Class

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Dim aaa As A = MyTryCast(Of A)(New B)
  Dim ccc As C = MyTryCast(Of B)(New C)
End Sub

Private Function MyTryCast(Of T As Class)(obj As Object) As Object
  Dim result As Object = TryCast(obj, T)
  If result Is Nothing Then Return Convert.DBNull
  Return result
End Function
```

`MyTryCast` does exactly what you are asking for, so `aaa` assignment works. Problem appears when you assign `DBNull` to `ccc` variable of type `C`. You would expect it to assign `DBNull` to `C`, because `C` cannot be converted to `B` (regular `TryCast` would return `Nothing`). Instead, you get `System.InvalidCastException`, because you cannot assign a `DBNull` to an instance of your custom class. Important thing to remember here - `Nothing` can be assigned to anything, `DBNull` can only be assigned to an `Object`. See [here for DBNull inheritance hierarchy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx).